# Cannot change colum names in JPA Eclipselink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I'm having problems making @Column(name="example") working.

I've got a User class:

```
@Entity
public class User {
     @Id
     private String username;
     ....
}
```

A Role one:

```
   @Entity
    public class Role {
         @Id
         private String name;
         ....
```

}

That are in a ManyToMany relationship. So I created a RoleMembership:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(UserRolePK.class)
public class RoleMembership {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="USERNAME")
    private User user;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ROLE")
    private Role role;
....
}
```

As you can see, the primary key is defined in UserRolePK:

```
public class UserRolePK{

    @Id
    @Column(name="ROLE")
    private String role;

    @Id
    @Column(name="USERNAME")
    private String user;
...
}
```

In this class I use @Column(name="USERNAME") and  @Column(name="ROLE") to force its name to that string, but it's not working: JPA gives it the default names USER_USERNAME and ROLE_NAME (that are in TABLE_ID format).
Can anyone help me finding the mistake?
Thanks,
Andrea

EDIT: 
I need to have three tables:

- user (username (pk), password ....)
- user_role (username, role_name)
- role (name (pk), description)

I cannot change User definition in my model.

Comment: Are you sure you are dropping the tables and recreating them on app startup?

Comment: In that case, my advice is irrelevant :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the annotations in `UserRolePK` and change your `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotations to `@JoinColumn` annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of PrimaryKeyJoinColumn does not seem to make sense.  I think you should be using just a @JoinColumn, or are you also mapping the columns as basics?

Perhaps include you complete class, and the DDL that is generated.

Comment: James, thank for your reply. Can I ask you to explain me what you bean by "mapping the columns as basics"? I edited the question adding the result I need to obtain. With the code you have seen, it works  (but this doesn't mean it's the right way, as you are telling me) except for the names of the columns. Thanks, A